# Remove or Ignore Variable if Input Field is Empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to construct an URL for an API based on the input that users type on the query form using JavaScript. The input of the text field is saved in a variable that is further joint together as a final URL. 
Nevertheless, not all input fields will be used all the time.

I was wondering how can you ignore that particular variable if its value is empty.

As I explained, I have a set of input fields:

```
<input id="whoValue"  type="text" value=""   placeholder="Who">    
<input id="whenStart" type="text" value="" placeholder="Start Date">
<input id="whenEnd" type="text" value="" placeholder="End Date">
<input id="whatValue"  type="text" value="" placeholder="What">
<button id="searchBtn">Search</button></br>
<input id="result" type="text" value="" placeholder="Resulting URL">
```

Then when the button is pressed, JavaScript joins the input fields even if their content is empty.

```
$('#searchBtn').click(function () {

    var url = 'http://particularURLof/';
    var who = "…WHO" + $('#whoValue').val();
    var what = "…WHAT"+ $('#whatValue').val();
    var when = "…YEAR[" + $('#whenStart').val() + "+TO+" + $('#whenEnd').val() + "]";
    var moreUrl = '…url End';

    var resultUrl = url + who + what + when + moreUrl;
    $("#result").val(resultUrl);

});
```

Therefore, as mentioned above, I am trying to construct that `resultUrl` only with the **variables** that **hold a value** in the **input field**.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trinkermedia/ngcngsc5/5/)  of what I have as well.

Comment: Well, what have you tried? You know how to check if a string is empty, right? So...

Comment: Yes, I have seen that I can use `.val().length >0` to check if the field is empty. As such: `$("#whoValue").val().length > 0`. 

But what I don't know is how then to join them together when constructing the final `resultUrl`.

Hope this clarifies more my question.

Comment: please google "How to check empty string in js"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short if else like:

```
var result = if_this_is_true ? true : false;
```

to give you an example with your code

```
$('#searchBtn').click(function () {

    var url     = 'http://particularURLof/';
    var who     = $('#whoValue').val().length > 0   ? "…WHO" + $('#whoValue').val() : '';
    var what    = $('#whatValue').val().length > 0  ? "…WHAT"+ $('#whatValue').val() : '';
    var moreUrl = '…url End';

    var resultUrl = who + what + moreUrl;
    $("#result").val(resultUrl);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n1jtrpmv/1/

Comment: Yes, perfect. I was having trouble with the logic, but this is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$('#searchBtn').click(function () {

```
var url = 'http://particularURLof/';
var who = $('#whoValue').val();
var what = $('#whatValue').val();
var whenStart = $('#whenStart').val();
var whatEnd = $('#whenEnd').val(); 
var moreUrl = "endOfUrl";

if( (who != '') && (what != '') && (whenStart != '') && (whenEnd != '') ) {
   var resultUrl = url + who + what + whenStart + whenEnd + moreUrl;
} 
else if( (who == '') && (what != '') && (whenStart != '') && (whenEnd != '') ) {
   var resultUrl = url + what + whenStart + whenEnd + moreUrl;
} 
else if( (who != '') && (what == '') && (whenStart != '') && (whenEnd != '') ) {
   var resultUrl = url + who + whenStart + whenEnd + moreUrl;
}
else if( (who != '') && (what != '') && ((whenStart == '') || (whenEnd == '')) ) {
   var resultUrl = url + who + what + moreUrl;
}

$("#result").val(resultUrl);
```

});